# Uniqueness of meets and joins in posets

Tags: order-theory, relations

Exercise 1.2.8 (Part 2), [p.8](http://books.google.com/books?id=mHptq6sqJRIC&pg=PA8), from *Categories for Types* by Roy L. Crole.

**Definition:** Let $X$ be a preordered set and $A \subseteq X$. A *join* of $A$, if such exists, is a least element in the set of upper bounds for $A$. A *meet* of $A$, if such exists, is a greatest element in the set of lower bounds for $A$.

**Exercise:** Suppose that $X$ is a poset (and thus also a preorder). Show that meets and joins in a poset are unique if they exist.

Comment: I have posted my solution as an answer and would appreciate any feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Please choose titles that describe the problem, not it's location.

Comment: @BillDubuque Is that better?

Comment: Much better, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should have linked to [your question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174313/examples-of-preorders-in-which-meets-and-joins-do-not-exist) with the first part of this exercise. (Definitions given there are relevant for this part, too.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I decided to add the definition here for completeness. Thanks for the link to the text ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A \subseteq X$ and suppose $x$ and $y$ are both joins of $A$. Then $x$ and $y$ are both upper bounds of $A$. So $A \le x$ and $A \le y$. But since $x$ and $y$ are joins of $A$ and $x, y \in X$, $y \le x$ and $x \le y$. Therefore, $x = y$ because because $\le$ is anti-symmetric. Meets are unique by a similar argument.

Comment: Your solution seems fine. Just a remark about notation - I am not sure whether $A\le x$ is frequently used as a shortcut for $(\forall a\in A) a\le x$. (But if it used this way in your course/book, then it is certainly ok for you to use this notation.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak That is the notation used in the textbook I am reading. When i typed this up, I wondered if it was a standard notation or not.